# Show/Hide nested list with css

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to show and hide onclick a nested list in a vertical navigation sidebar with CSS? if not what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Yes there are loads of ways of doing this - what have you tried so far?

Comment: many ways..Jquery ad example...what did attempt?

Comment: i have been trying to find a solution via css but have not been successful but thats about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How do you want to hide it?
Best is to use simple CSS

```css
ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

You can obviously add some linear transitions/and or fade ins using either CSS or jQuery to avoid the visual jumps.

**EDIT**

For onClick, use jQuery.

```js
$(".mySelector").click(function() {
    $(this).find("li").find("ul").show();
});
```

You can replace the show() with fadeIn as well, and I'm assuming by default `display: none` is there already.

Also, you may wanna use bind if these elements are generated dynamically.

Comment: i edited my question, i know how to do it this way, i wanted to know is how to do it by clicking, not hovering, because hovering can get annoying.

Comment: Cool, you might as well use `.toggle()` since you want to show/hide and not just show.

Comment: The problem with this is, it toggles all my nested lists from just clicking on one nested list, how can i make it so it only toggles the first list and then the next list if clicked etc

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to show the nested list `onclick`?

I'd suggest to go with jQuery (JavasScript) and do something like this

```
$('ul.outerlist>li').on(`click`, function(){
  $(this).find('ul.innerlist').toggle();
});
```

EDIT: that's the easiest way I can imagine. Anything else depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
ul#childlist
{
    display:none;
}

    ul#parentlist li:hover ul#childlist
    { 
        display: block;
    }
```

You might have to increase the boarders or margins to get it to run smother.
You could also look up CSS transitions, they're great for getting JavaScript-y looking things without any JavaScript.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using jquery(javascript framework).

If looking for sidebar then this link will help you:

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/143/jQuery-Advanced-docking-Side-Menu

If loking for Vertical menu type something then this:

http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-mega-menu-plugin/examples/